# Oracle Secure Backup + Amazon S3 / RMAN-06172: no AUTOBACKUP found or specified handle is not a valid copy or piece

Tags: oracle, rman

I have backup in Amazon S3 that was created without AUTOBACKUP settings.

trying to recover parameter file:

```
RUN
{
  SET DBID 3427966416;
  ALLOCATE CHANNEL ch1 DEVICE TYPE sbt parms 'SBT_LIBRARY=/home/oracle/S3BCKP/lib/libosbws.so ENV=(OSB_WS_PFILE=/home/oracle/S3BCKP/config/s3backup.cfg)';
  RESTORE SPFILE TO PFILE '/home/oracle/initSUPERPROD.ora' FROM AUTOBACKUP MAXDAYS 12;
  SHUTDOWN ABORT;
}
```

then I get:

```
channel ch1: no AUTOBACKUP in 7 days found
released channel: ch1
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 04/20/2021 09:21:38
RMAN-06172: no AUTOBACKUP found or specified handle is not a valid copy or piece
```

Backups are in the bucket. How to restore any of them?

upd. downloaded 0000000001 chunk that is relates to controlfile and spfile backuppiece with awscli utility

```
restore controlfile from '/home/oracle/0000000001';

channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring control file
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 04/20/2021 10:28:40
ORA-19870: error while restoring backup piece /home/oracle/0000000001
ORA-19505: failed to identify file "/home/oracle/0000000001"
ORA-27048: skgfifi: file header information is invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not setup bucket name that was originally used duting backup creation:

```
echo "OSB_WS_BUCKET=mycompany-oracle-database-bucket" >> /home/oracle/S3BCKP/config/s3backup.cfg
```